# Prove that in a tree where each node has 0 or 2 children, number of nodes with 0 child is one more than the number of nodes with 2 children

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

How to prove

In a tree where every node has either $0$ or $2$ children, the number of nodes with $0$ child is $1$ more than the number of nodes with $2$ children.

Answer (score 3):

This can be proven by induction. What you describe is a [Full binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), and it has a convenient induction definition:

- a single node (or leaf) is a full binary tree;
- a tree with two children that are full binary trees is a full binary tree.

This permits a [structural induction proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) of the property you want:

- prove that it is true for a single node tree;
- suppose that it is true for two full binary trees $a$, $b$, then prove that it is true for the node $N(a, b)$ with $a$ and $b$ as children.